# Single signon web-based authentication system

Tags: php, security, authentication, single-sign-on

I'm hoping for feedback on an authentication system I have designed.

The requirements are to create a closed, single sign on web environment, where by once one of our employees visit one of our web applications, they are asked to sign in with their credentials backed by our LDAP. Once signed in, they retain this login for a set time period, or the browser session, and across all our web applications. Much how Google's web properties work with a google account, but for our internal systems.

The users themselves operate from windows, mac or linux, and some from just tablets, so this authentication environment needs to exist solely online, kerberos with mod_auth_kerb etc aren't going to cut it.

All our current web applications use PHP.

The system I have so far works like below.

There exists one central authentication system, which I will call the Authentication Handler, or "handler" for short, and one or more authentication "client" web apps, which I will call Authentication Requestor, or "requestor" for short. I will call the user and their browser just "user".

Also, for it to work, the requestor needs to be preconfigured at the handler with a unique `requestor_id` and return URL for that ID.
A private key for handler is generated and a public key given to all requestors before hand too.

### user visits requestor

1. user enters URL for requestor.
2. no session exists for this user on requestor, so requestor creates a new `SESSION_ID` in PHP (with the built in session handler and `session_start`).
3. the session has no authentication, so requestor will then generate a URL to the configured handler consisting of two parts, an `authrequest` token and an `envelope`.

   1. requestor first regenerate a new session_id (`session_regenerate_id` in PHP) for this auth request for the client.
   2. requestor then generates a random password, in this case using PHP's `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` and stores this in the session data
   3. requestor then encrypts the `SESSION_ID` using `AES256` with the random password for the `authrequest` in PHP using `openssl_encrypt`.
   4. requestor then generates envelope data by concatenating it's unique `requestor_id`, a ':', and the base64-encoded random password.
   5. requestor's envelope data is then encrypted using the pre-shared public key for the handler using `openssl_public_encrypt` in PHP.
4. requestor then sends a `location:` header to user that contains the encrypted `envelope` and the `authrequest` as URL parameters to handler.
5. handler will decrypt the envelope using it's private key, and separate the clientID and password.
6. handler will check the `requestor_id` to see if we have this configured, if not, will inform the user that the requestor was not recognised.
7. handler will authenticate the user (in this case, via asking for username and password and checking against LDAP and/or via a preauthenticated session)
8. handler will then generate a return `authtoken` to requestor

   1. handler will decrypt the `SESSION_ID` from `authrequest` using the decrypted and decoded password from the envelope
   2. handler will encrypt a new string containing `SESSION_ID` and an ID of the logged in credentials (username, GUID, etc) with the decrypted and decoded password from the envelope
9. handler then sends a `location:` header to user that contains the `authtoken` as URL parameter to a preconfigured URL for this `requestor_id`.
10. requestor receives the request, and will decrypt the token using the password in the users session.
11. requestor will confirm the `SESSION_ID` matches the users current session, else it will restart authentication.
12. requestor can then use the returned crednetialID to identify a local user as authenticated.

This process can be repeated across different systems to give a single signon behaviour.

So, questions:

1. Does anyone know of a pre-existing, standardised authentication system that meets the requirements and preforms similarly to above?
2. If not, and given that I'm no security expert, is there anything above that would could be broken? i.e. what is/are the weak point(s) of this method?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Kerberos: http://web.mit.edu/kerberos/www/
Or you implement an internal OpenID system: http://openid.net/
There are also several PHP libraries for OpenID: http://openid.net/developers/libraries/

Comment: Kerberos is a no-go because the iPad, AFAIK, does not have built in support for kerberos. I thought about OpenID, but I don't need multiple providers, just one, and also to support the auto-signin the client system (web service) needs to not ask for an ID, unlike in OpenID

Comment: You could use certificate based authentication.

Comment: certificates could work like that. The disadvantages are quite high, in that management and installation is more difficult. I touched on the fact that our user use different clients, but the reason is that our field offices provide their own computers and support, so credentials based on ID and password are easy to remember and support, and don't require setup to work on every client machine. But it would be a potential alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Your base64 encoding of the password *before* encryption doesn't really make any sense (for me at least), as it is a function mostly used for serializing data that is to be communicated elsewhere. However, after the envelope is encrypted, you have binary data again, so what you might want to do is serialize the ciphertext.

Also, you might want to check out whether it is possible to do hashing of the credentials at the client-side (1000 times iterated and salted MD5 or SHA-* is fine). You could check out [RFC2617](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2617.txt) (HTTP Digest Access Authentication) for inspiration. This is to counter the passwords' vulnerability while decrypted at the server.

Comment: You are correct about base64 encoding the password, it's likely completely unnecessary, I think maybe I had added that to avoid collisions with the ":" separator?

Comment: As for hashing the password, the password never leaves the authentication server, here referred to as handler. Only the "ID" of a user is passed back to the client, i.e. requestor

Comment: Ow, you're right about the separator. You should probably leave the base64 - my bad. As for the hashing, it's only a suggestion for moving to a good old RFC, which is easily extendable and general. As long as both server and client handle the hashes the same way, you're free to do whatever. Nonce values used in RFC2617 are powerful for setting session time, etc, and you can also "hash in" a private key of the server (at the server side) to provide mutual authentication. This was a messy explanation, but it might be very far from what you're looking for. If you want more info on it, please tell

Comment: I like the thinking here, but maybe I'm misunderstanding how this applies to the sequence above. The only password that is shared between client and server (requestor and handler) is a randomly generated one on the client-side. There's no pre-shared password, only PublicKey-PrivateKey to encrypt the randomly generated encryption password. How could hashing be introduced here?

Comment: It's the same principle, but where you pass an encrypted random variable, Digest authentication hashes a "proof of identity" (i.e. another hash (originally MD5(username:realm:password)) together with a timestamp for session-validity, and passes that to the server. Your scheme authenticates by showing proof of a session id, where the secret value here is a credential set. 

_However_, the credential set (called A1 in the RFC) can be an arbitrary value (an "identifier"), as long as it is stored hashed (called HA1) at both locations and handled the same way.

Comment: To clarify, both are challenge response authentication schemes and yours probably would work great. But I think there are enough similarities between the two to use the established scheme.

Comment: I do apologise for not understanding this yet, perhaps I'm thinking too narrow mindedly. Currently, other than requestor_id (which is neither random nor secure), and the public key of the handler (for encryption because authrequest and envelope are given to the user/browser in the location header), nothing else is pre shared from the requestor, nor does it ask the user/browser to share anything with the requestor. What can be hashed on both sides to be compared?

Comment: You would need some sort of symmetrical secret on both endpoints (the hash in my below examples).

In original HTTP Digest access control lists are stored as lines of [username]:[realm]:[h(username:realm:password)], but could easily use e.g. [client_id]:[h(client_id:random_GUUID_for_this_client_id]. The crux is proving knowledge of the last value.

When a user is to authenticate, he could navigate to the appropriate "authentication site", which is digest protected (set up on the server). Authentication could be done automatically by way of a browser plugin (Chrome supports this well).